# Two level domain names point to different directories with apache

Tags: php, apache

I am configuring the two level domain name，and want to achieve the following effect.

```
www.myaomain.com  -> /root/
test.mydomain.com -> /root/test
vuelar.mydomain.com -> /root/vuelar/public   //Here is laravel
```

Here is my configure

[image]

Here is result

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What doesn't work? did you change your hosts file?

Comment: it doesn't work,all will point to `/root`

Answer (score 1):

Add your domain and it's subdomains to your hosts file.

```
127.0.0.0       xxxxxx.com
127.0.0.0       admin.xxxxxx.com
127.0.0.0       vuelar.xxxxxx.com
```

Hosts file: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: It's useful locally, and it's no use on the server.

Comment: And for the remote, you need to specify DNS records for subdomains.